# I have JavaScript code at the bottom of the page but images still load after?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm referencing my JavaScript files before the closing body tag, hoping they will be parsed last (as they're not needed until last). However when I analyse activity with PageSpeed in Firebug, the images seem to be requested last.

How can I make the images higher priority than the JavaScript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute your javascript commands in the onLoad-Event the images should be read first. After the page is fully loaded the onLoad-Event is executed.

Comment: i'm using jquery document.ready, so is that doing it before images?

Comment: @Haroldo: Yes, the document ready event will fire before images are loaded.

Comment: you should try $(window).load(function() {};

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `document.ready` is before images. If you want it to run after images are loaded you need to use

```
$(window).ready(function() {});
```

Answer (score -2):

Load your images outside of the $.ready() function